# Group a dataframe on one column and take max from one column and its corresponding value from the other col

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a large dataframe which has a similar pattern as below:

```
    X   Y   Z
0   a   p   2
1   a   q   5
2   a   r   6
3   a   s   3
4   b   w   10
5   b   z   20
6   b   y   9
7   b   x   20
```

And can be constructed as:

```
df = {
    'X': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
    'Y': ['p', 'q', 'r', 's', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
    'Z': [2, 5, 6, 3, 10, 20, 9, 5]
}
```

Now I want to group this dataframe by the first column i.e., `X` and take `max` from the `Z` column and its corresponding value from `Y`. And if there are two max values in `Z`, then I would like to take alphabetically first value from `Y`.

So my expected result would look like:

```
X   Y   Z
a   r   6
b   x   20
```

I have tried `groupby('X', as_index=False).agg({'Z': 'max', 'Y': 'first'})` but this selects max from `Z` and first from `Y` both at the same time.

Additionally I know there is a `pd.series.groupby.nlargest(1)` approach, but this would take a lot of time for my dataset.

Any suggestions on how could I proceed would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: @jezrael Its not a dupe..And your answer in comment will not work when there are two equal max values in column `Z` because we also have to keep in mind that alphabetically smallest value in column `Y` is to be selected.

Comment: @jezrael I don't see my exact answer in the dupe...And IMHO the marked dupe is not in any way related to this question

Comment: I too agree that this question is not particularly related to the one mentioned above

Comment: @jezrael yes i am sure.

Comment: @jezrael Check `And if there are two max values in Z, then I would like to take alphabetically first value from Y.` from the question

Comment: @ShubhamSharma - oops, you are right. Sorry, I miss it.

Comment: sorry, I was wrong, so reopened question.

Comment: @jezrael would you mind showing your answer which is not publicly visible now, I think it could be useful to solve a problem. Thanks:)

Comment: @YashvanderBamel - Answer is wrong. because not sorted `Y`

Comment: I know but there is something else i wanna see, you can hide it soon after

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us try [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) + [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df.sort_values(['X', 'Z', 'Y'], ascending=[True, False, True]).drop_duplicates('X')
```

---

```
   X  Y   Z
2  a  r   6
5  b  x  20
```